# FB.ui with method 'feed' is resulting in an 'unknown error' and CAPTCHA request

Tags: captcha, facebook-stream-story

We're using code that we've used before, so I suspect that this may be site-related.  In using a standard:

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    app_id: '<?= $LDP->config->facebook->id ?>',
    name: 'Post Name',
    link: flink,
    picture: "https://www.domain.ca/templates/visual/images/share.gif",
    caption: "Caption",
    description: 'Join the fun today!',
    actions: [
      { name: "Check it out!", link: flink }
    ]
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

It first displays the expected share dialog, and when you click the button at bottom right to go through with the stream publication, a new popup appears with:

Title: Require Captcha

unknown error

Security Check
please enter the text below

[captcha appears]

The only button is "Ok".  Correctly solving the Captcha results in a crash (Facebook servers throwing a 500 error).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug with Facebook (broken captcha issue).  The pop-up is an innate anti-spam system, but people should be able to succeed with the CAPTCHA. I'd filed a private bug with Facebook, and it's slated to be fixed apparently.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the bug you reported?

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing this too. I can confirm that changing the domain in the link makes it all good.

I got a parallel domain for our app and after three days the same Captcha with "Unknown error" appeared. Best of all – if a user gives the correct Captcha words the post will still fail. This is pretty annoying and we're getting complaints from our users.

Comment: It started manifesting when the site we built was put in the media, so as you can imagine, we felt the pain too.  We had 30000 people driven to this, and the complaints where substantial.  Did you have any potentially 'spammy' words in your URL? I had the word 'win', I wonder if it was done just by way of URL examination.

Comment: Our app in question is a funny little slotmachine that holds the images of politicians running for president in FIN. No spammy words, and all the words are in finnish. Tried to lint the url too, but the same thing. I think FB might have some kind of automated spam prevention mechanisms, because the second domain i had for the app got the Captcha treatment after a few days of the release.

Comment: I was hopeful to get in touch with anyone who can give official info at Facebook, but they herd us into here with there automated email responses -- you tried going that route?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling FB.init() before calling FB.ui() to see if that helps get things in sync.  Also be sure to specify the channelUrl in the init call too.

Comment: If this sheds any light, changing the domain in the link that is shared seems to make everything work.  Could it be that the domain I'm using, is being spam-trapped or is blacklisted or something of the sort?  If so, where to get help?

Comment: It very well might be.  You should also see if the link in question being shared can be linted correctly by https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Really odd since it was a new domain. It did contain the word 'win', which I suspect was the culprit.  The domain is being pulled in correct using the debug tool, all checks pass.  What a pain, and there's no channel of communication with anyone at FB who could confirm :/

Comment: I changed the domain, it worked.  A few hours later, stops working.  Seems like someone, or something, is working against us.

Comment: Maybe it's a banned IP and your server is sharing IPs with that one.  Also check your email at the email address on file for the app id.  Maybe facebook has sent you something.